# Why does EF remove child entities when detaching?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, detach

I need to do something like ...

1. get a db context (UtilitiesContext)
2. query it for some data (Watched Directories)
3. Also pull children from the db when i pull the WD's (AdditionalData)
4. Dispose of context
5. Continue to use entities

...

```
// step 1
using (var db = new UtilitiesContext(false))
{
    var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { MaxDepth = 2, ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore };

    // step 2
    var dirs = db.GetAll<WatchedDirectory>();

    // step 3 (lazy load and serialize the WD and its additional data)
    log.Debug(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dirs, jsonSettings));

    foreach (var d in dirs)
    {
        try
        {
            log.Debug("    Initialising monitoring for path " + d.UNCPath);

            // detach the object and its data items from the db
            db.Detach(d);
            d.AdditionalData.ForEach(i => db.Detach(i));

            // here the AdditionalData property serialises an empty array
            log.Debug(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d, jsonSettings));

// step 4 happens down here
```

My problem is that I get all the data I want in the first log output  (line labelled step 3)
And then later when I repeat that the child collection is gone and all I did was detach the entities from the context.

My detach method looks like this ...

```
public void Detach(object entity)
{
    Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
}
```

Comment: If you are going to dispose the context you should just map them to DTOs first. I believe you will have a lot more issue then just this if you follow your current path. Working with entity objects outside of a context scope is asking for problems.

Comment: Yeh I had considered it ... these are very simple entities though so I thought this might possible to save the code duplication

Comment: I've tried to do similar things in the past and it ALWAYS comes back to bite you in the arse eventually, easier to do the mappings now than have it work up to a later point in time where you need to re-write a much larger amount of code when it finally does blow up on you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF is a funny beast, this is ultimate cure for detaching an entity from a context ...

```
var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { MaxDepth = 2, ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore };
var dirs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WatchedDirectory>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.GetAll<WatchedDirectory>().ToList(), jsonSettings));
```

There are probably better practices for this but this bull in china shop approach solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you detach the parent entity from the context, you can no longer use lazy loading of child entities (which in your case, you should never do anyway, b/c the performance is going to suffer greatly). The more performant method is to use includes() to load the required children up front. This will save you additional calls to the db. For example, if each parent has 2 children, you would be making 1 call for the parent, and an additional 2 calls for every child. Very inefficient.

Your method of serializing something in order to deserialize something is a poor way to get DTO's out. You should do mapping (possibly with Automapper), or turn off EF proxy handling and lazy loading, which has a similar effect.